# Transition between scales

Tags: piano, scales, transition

I'm new to music theory and I've been learning quite a bit but still have many questions. I would like to know how I could transition between scales on the piano. For example there is a song (a slow song if it matters) in particular where it transitions from D scale to G scale. I was able to decode the transition by ear which results in D C Bm Am7 (would normal Am work?) D G. I would do the bass on my left hand while I do some melody with my right hand. I would like to know what this particular set of notes is called or if there is a specific formula or rule that could help me. 
Thanks again!

Comment: I believe by scales in this context you mean [key signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature). building of that I think you are talking about [key changes or modulation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_(music)) I'm sorry I'm not able to recommend a piece of music that has these as I am new to learning piano as well, but knowing these terms should help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Not at all sure what this is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the bass (I assume) progression is D C Bm Am7 D G, which would be:

- D F# A
- C E G
- B D F#
- A C E G (which is in homage to CMaj from before, hence the added 7th)
- D F# A
- G B D

These are all 7 notes of the G major scale (or E natural minor, but the progression ends on a G chord, so it's definitely major).

The interval between D (the root of the first chord) and G (the root of the last one) is a [perfect fifth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fifth) (7 semitones). This is one of the 2 most common [cadences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence) found in music (the other being a transition from a [perfect fourth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fourth) to the [tonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonic_(music))).

So, umm, there is no scale transition here, and I don't quite understand your question.

Also, an Xm7 chord will *always* contain a major triad from a major key relative to X. In your example, we have a CMaj chord (C E G). The relative minor of C (take a look at the [Circle of Fourths/Fifths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths)) is A. So if we want to build an Am7 chord, we can simply take A and add the notes of the C major triad on top of it. That's one of the beauties of m7 chords.

Answer (score -2):

It's a direct transition and it happens on the C major chord.

If you want to learn more about optimum smoothness into transitions you should learn about hexatonic scales.

But in this case the reason D to G transitions smoothly is because it differs in notes by 1 note C# to C as G major is also D mixolydian.

Of the major modes it would take 4 transitions D Major to D Mixolydian to D Dorian to D Minor where each scale changes just one note but as I said hexatonic scales take less scales to get there just 1 transition to go from major to minor the reason behind this is simple there is one less note than hepatonic, it's much easier to write them out yourself to find them like this...

Ex.

|1|m2|M2|m3|M3|4|b5|5|m6|M6|m7|M7|

|1|      |M2|      |M3|4|    |5|      |M6|      |      |

|1|      |M2|      |      |4|    |5|      |M6|m7|      |

|1|      |M2|m3|      |4|    |5|      |      |m7|      |

It will sound more varied than hepatonic transitions do as in total you are using 8 notes.

Jimi Hendrix' Little wing shows his transition system very well.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: You can delete your answer by clicking on "_Delete_" in the lower-left corner if you aren't happy with it anymore.